# Modificate rxbag tool

Tags: ros, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I need to make a modification rxbag tool I will appreciate if someone could tell me how can I start because I don’t know what packages I have to modify, my intention is to change the time line it a pears when you open a bag with rxbag so it apears somehow the distance ,I will know the constant speed of the robot. Can someone give me a tip of how to start.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64758/modificate-rxbag-tool/) by [sonia](https://answers.ros.org/users/5114/sonia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rxbag` is, [as it's noted on its web site, deprecated](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxbag#Deprecated) since ROS Groovy and taken over by [rqt_bag](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_bag). Thus I highly recommend you switch over to `rqt_bag`. Some advantages of `rqt`, the new GUI framework of ROS, are [noted here](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt#Advantage_of_rqt_framework) including the availability of sample codes for ROS' GUI applications, which might help you a lot upon your GUI programming.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1